# Split string into array using multi-character delimiter

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I need to split a string into an array. My problem is that the delimiter is a 3 character one: `_-_` 

For example:

```
db2-111_-_oracle12cR1RAC_-_mariadb101
```

I'd need to create the following array:

```
db2-111
oracle12cR1RAC
mariadb101
```

Similar questions followed this approach:

```
str="db2-111_-_oracle12cR1RAC_-_mariadb101"
arr=(${str//_-_/ })
echo ${arr[@]}
```

Even if the array is created, it has been split uncorrectly:

```
db2 
111 
oracle12cR1RAC 
mariadb101
```

It seems that the "-" character in the first item causes the array's split function to fail.
Can you suggest a fix for it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can, replace the `_-_` sequences with another *single* character that you can use for field splitting. For example,

```
$ str="db2-111_-_oracle12cR1RAC_-_mariadb101"
$ str2=${str//_-_/#}
$ IFS="#" read -ra arr <<< "$str2"
$ printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
db2-111
oracle12cR1RAC
mariadb101
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sed` to do what you want, i.e. writting something like that :

```
str="db2-111_-_oracle12cR1RAC_-_mariadb101"
arr=($(sed 's/_-_/ /g' <<< $str))
echo ${arr[0]}
```

**Edit :**

The reason `arr=(${str//_-_/ })` didn't work is that when you write it like that, everything inside `${ ... }` is considered as 1 element of the array. So, using `sed`, or even simply `arr=($(echo ${str//_-_/ }))` will produce the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it though and it produces a 1 sized array unfortunately: `echo ${arr[0]}
db2 111   oracle12cR1RAC   mariadb101`

Comment: Using escapes didn't work either `sed "s/\_\-\_/ /g"`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the exact code I gave? Copy/pasting my code works on `zsh`, `bash-4.4` and `bash-3.2` on my computer (using GNU sed)

Comment: Indeed a bit weird. The code is the same. I'm running bash 4.3.43(1) release

Comment: @FrancescoMarchioni That's the output you'll get in `bash` 4.3 if you have `IFS="_-_"`, which seems like something you might have tried and forgot to reset. This code assumes that `IFS` has its default value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<<<'db2-111_-_oracle12cR1RAC_-_mariadb101' | 

{m,g}awk NF=NF FS='_[-]_' OFS='\n'

db2-111
oracle12cR1RAC
mariadb101
```

if you like the fringe but ultra concise `RS` syntax, it's

```
mawk ~ RS='_-_|\n'

   or

mawk \$_ RS='_-_|\n'

   or simply

mawk RS RS='_-_|\n'

db2-111
oracle12cR1RAC
mariadb101
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
$ echo "db2-111_-_oracle12cR1RAC_-_mariadb101" | perl -F/_-_/ -ne ' { print "$F[0]\n$F[1]\n$F[2]" } '
db2-111
oracle12cR1RAC
mariadb101
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using replacement of `_-_` with a NUL byte since we cannot make a safe assumption that some character like `#` or `;` or `:` will not be present in input strings.

```bash
readarray -d '' arr < <(
   awk -F'_-_' -v OFS='\0' '{ORS=OFS; $1=$1} 1' <<< "$str")

declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="db2-111" [1]="oracle12cR1RAC" [2]="mariadb101")
```

Note that due to use of `readarray` it will require BASH ver 4+